# What does '# of Cs' mean?

Tags: consonants, words, word-boundaries

The symbol # refers to the word boundary, which is the beginning and the ending of a word. So does the phrase

> # of Cs

mean that a consonant is the first or last letter in a word?

The whole sentence (found in my professor's notes) is

> # of Cs always larger than # of Vs

Comment: My guess is that the # means 'number' here? It doesn't seem to make sense to say that a word boundary is larger...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tragically, the letter "#" has two meanings. In linguistics, it is used to refer to a word boundary. More generally (i.e. not in the special usage of linguists), it (the [number sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)) stands for "number". The consequence of shorthand is obscurity.

So, the entire sentence should probably read,
*"the number of consonants is always larger than the number of vowels"*.

Comment: Polysemy is hardly tragic...

Comment: @curiousdanni Elatedly, you're right...